# Got an error when try to add unit tests for method arugment type checking in clojure

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I am new to clojure, below is my code

```
(ns my.class.package
    (:require [clojure.tools.logging :as log]
              [schema.core :as s]))

(s/defn my-method :- CandidateInfo [candidates :- [CandidateInfo] goal :- Goal]
  (doseq [candiate candidates]
    (s/validate CandidateInfo candidate))
  (s/validate Goal goal)
  ......)
```

The unit test I had is

```
(testing "test bad input schema"
           (let [candidates [{:bad-attr1 "123" :bad-attr2 "456"}]
                 goal {:id "123" }]
             (is (thrown? ExceptionInfo
                          (try
                            (my-class/my-method candidates goal)
                            (catch ExceptionInfo e
                              (throw e)))))))
```

The error I got is

```
ERROR in (test-my-method) (core.clj:155)
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Value does not match schema: {:id missing-required-key, :name missing-required-key}
at schema.core$validator$fn__14239.invoke (core.clj:155)
    schema.core$validate.invokeStatic (core.clj:164)
    schema.core$validate.invoke (core.clj:159)
    my.class.package.my-class$eval32123$my_method__32128$fn__32129.invoke (my-class.clj:36)
......
```

My understanding is that I did expect an ExceptionInfo thrown in my unit testing. However, the error kept saying that I expect nil. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(require '[schema.test :as st])

(st/deftest SchemaTest
    (testing "test bad input schema"
        (let [candidates [{:bad-attr1 "123" :bad-attr2 "456"}]
              goal       {:id "123"}]
            (is (thrown? ExceptionInfo
                    (try
                        (my-class/my-method candidates goal)
                        (catch ExceptionInfo e
                            (throw e))))))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying, @akond. So you are suggesting to make sure the deftest is the one from schema.test? I did give a try. No luck, still the same error.

Comment: In this case I need a minimal working reproducible code to investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

If your code actually throws an `ExceptionInfo` this works:

```clj
(defn my-method [_ _]
  (throw (ex-info "help!" {}))) ; intentionally throw ExceptionInfo

(deftest bad-input-schema-test
  (testing "test bad input schema"
    (let [candidates [{:bad-attr1 "123" :bad-attr2 "456"}]
          goal {:id "123"}]
      (is (thrown? clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo (my-method candidates goal))))))
```

You don't need to try-catch and rethrow, though it also works.

Maybe your code does not throw?

I assume schema.test uses clojure.test in namespace:

```clj
(:require
 [clojure.test :refer [deftest testing is]])
```